# Set element's ID using increment

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need set ID and I use only template and link.
ID look like

```
id="number1"
id="number2"
id="number3"
...
```

> **id="number' + (index++)'"'**

But ID not generated. It's not cycle.

If I use $compile MyApp doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var index=0; //Iterator

angular.module('app', [])
 .directive('tttt', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
                value: '@'
            },
      template: '<input type="text" id="number' + (index++) + '" ></input>', 

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.value = attrs.value;
     }
    };
});

</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="app">
    <tttt value="http://google.com">google</tttt>
    <tttt value="http://mail.ru">mail</tttt>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is the purpose of this index, but assuming you need one for automation or another case, I think the best approach is keep your index on a service (never on window as a global var!), get it when needed and increment it when needed. Or if you always get an increment, do it in one method.

So we'll have something like:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
 .service('MyIdService', function(){
    var index = 0;

    this.getAndIncrement = function () {
        return index++;
    }
});
```

And the usage in the directive will be:

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .directive('tttt', ['MyIdService', function(MyIdService){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
                value: '@'
            },
      template: '<input type="text" id="number{{index}}" ></input>', 

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.index = MyIdService.getAndIncrement();
     }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Did you remove your directive before inserting this one? Can you please provide a plunker?

Comment: Yes. It's my mistake)) Your code works. But it doesn't work in my application

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's hard to understand what can be the problem.

Comment: If you have several directives on the same element which require an isolated scoep (which is represented by 'scope: {...}' on a directive definition). If so then this problem is unrelated to my solution, try to use 'scope: true' instead and see if you still get an error. If you still get an error, please reproduce by plunker or jsfiddle, since I cannot know what is wrong without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {value: '@'},
        template: '<input type="text" id="number' + (index++) + '" ></input>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.value = attrs.value;
        }
    };
});
```

With:

```
function () {
    var template = '<input type="text" id="number' + index + '" ></input>';
    index++;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {value: '@'},
        template: template ,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.value = attrs.value;
        }
    };
});
```

That should properly increment your index.

Comment: is index a global variable??

Comment: no. I got id="number0" id=number0 id=number0 number0 e.t.))

Comment: That's because the code running before the return clause runs only once in the app's lifecycle, so the template has index 0, you then increment index but nothing calls this code again.

Comment: Hm. I just replaced my angular.min.js. And it works now.